# Eclipse Displays Popup on Rename/Refactor Command

Tags: eclipse

I am getting a popup to choose a command to run when pressing the rename/refactor shortcut. I highlight a file in the Package Explorer, press the command, and popup!?!?!

I have used Eclipse for 13 years, and I have never seen anything like this issue. The rename/refactor shortcut has worked flawlessly on every other instance of Eclipse I have ever used.

The closest help which Google could find is to open the shortcut preferences. I unbinded every command associated to the shortcut binding. Still, the popup continues to appear.

If any of this helps, I am on MacOS Monterey 12.5 and using Eclipse 4.22.0.

[Shortcut Command Choice Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUKsm.png)

Comment: The language you're working with would be relevant here, as well as whether it still happens in the current release.

Comment: Two commands are bound to the same key shortcut. You can change the bindings in Preferences > General > Keys.

Comment: @greg-449 I already went through that, to unbind the commands. The preferences show no command binded to option+command+r. The pop up still shows.

Comment: @nitind I have updated to Eclipse 4.25.0.

I played around with the key bindings again, in Preferences. I observed the following, in reference to commands being binded to option+command+r:

1. Only with Rename :: In Windows :: File
I can rename a file in Package Explorer but not refactor-rename in Java classes.

2. Only with Rename - Refactoring :: In Windows :: Refactor - Java
I can refactor-rename in Java classes but get the popup when I try to rename a file in Package Explorer.

Comment: 3. Bindings in both 1 and 2
I can refactor-rename in Java classes but get the popup when I try to rename a file in Package Explorer.

I know older versions of Eclipse, going back to at least 2009, had no issues with being binded to both. So I have no idea why newer versions would have this issue.

Comment: I have a project with a Gradle build file and SQL files. I ran the above configurations with a Java project and class, after I updated my Eclipse.